# Hitroi game "Square between pair" technique

Tags: prolog

I want to program this strategy "square between pair" in the game of Hitori
I tried a lot but without interest.
this the site: https://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/hitori/techniques

```
unshaded(X,Y):-cell(X,Y,_).

circle_between_a_pair_row(I,J,X,S):-
   num_in_raw(I,X,Z),
   write(Z),
   Z>=2,X == I+2 ,
   X\=I+1,
   S is I+1,
   unshaded(S,J,_),
   write(" Unshaded cell")
;  write(" not Unshaded cell").

circle_between_a_pair_col(I,J,X,S):-
   num_in_col(J,X,Z),
   Z>=2,write(Z),X == J+2 ,
   X \=J+1,
   unshaded(I,S,_),
   write(" Unshaded cell")
;  write(" not Unshaded cell").
```

Comment: Can you show your current approach?

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Ok, I will revise my question